# Need help making a tip calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a program that will take a number and multiply it by .15 so you know how much of a tip you need to leave.

I tried to put my bill input into a new variable in my function because I would get the tip total when I took the `number ()` out of my new variable, but doing this lead to nothing happening as JavaScript doesn't know it's a number

```
   <body>
    <input id="bill" placeholder ="How much was you meal?" />

    <button onclick ="tip()"> submit</button>

    <script> let bill = document.querySelector("#bill")

        function tip(){

            let yourTip = number( bill.value * .15)
            let total = yourTip * bill

            console.log ("Your tip  is $" + yourTip)
            console.log ("Your total after the tip is $" + total)
        }
    </script>
   </body>
```

I don't need to print it on the screen just in the console and the tip % does not need to change.

Comment: Maybe parseInt will help you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Also your declaration of bill is global not block so you should use var not let

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 <input id="bill" type="number" placeholder="How much was you meal?" />

<button onclick="tip()">submit</button>

<script>
  function tip() {
    var bill = parseInt(document.getElementById("bill").value);
    console.log(bill);

    let yourTip = bill * 0.15;
    let total = yourTip + bill;

    console.log("Your tip  is $" + yourTip);
    console.log("Your total after the tip is $" + total);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: parseInt should be set for bill before any math is done.

Comment: why whats the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<style>
  body {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<body>
    <input id="bill" placeholder ="How much was you meal?" />

    <button onclick ="tip()">Calculate</button>
    <h1 id="tip">Tip: $0</h1>
    <h1 id="total">Total: $0</h1>
    <script> let bill = document.querySelector("#bill")

        function tip(){
   let bill = document.getElementById('bill').value;
            let billNum = parseInt(bill);
            let yourTip = billNum * .15;
            let total = yourTip + billNum;

            document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = "Tip: $" + yourTip;
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "Total: $" + total;
        }
    </script>
   </body>
```

Let's break it down:

When you get the value of an input field, without specifying the type, JavaScript stores the value as a string.  To turn that string into a number, you need to use `parseInt(x)`, which tells the browser that the string is now a number, as you can't multiply a piece of text by a number.  You can then multiply that number by the tip percentage.

Additionally, you also multiplied the tip by the bill.  I added some styling, as well as using `innerHTML` instead of `console.log()` to display the tip and the total bill.

Answer (score 0):

in python, you can do like this

print('Welcome to the tip calculator')

total_bill = float(input("What was the total bill? "))

what_percentage = float(input("What percentage tip would you like to give? "))

tip_percentage = (total_bill * what_percentage) / 100

total_cost = total_bill +  tip_percentage

people = int(input("How many people to split the bill? "))
split_value = round(total_cost / people, 2)

print('Each person should pay' + str(split_value))

Comment: But the OP wants JavaScript...